# emberjs: call a function after all templates are ready/visible

Tags: templates, ember.js, rendering

I need to perform an action after the app starts and has rendered itself. What I did to achieve this, was adding the **didInsertElement** to the main template and call a controller method to perform the actual action, something like this:

```
Sp.IndexView = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'index',

    didInsertElement: function() {
        this.controller.switchMenuItem() ;
    }
}) ;

Sp.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({

    switchMenuItem: function() {
        $('#index').addClass('nice-animation') ;
        ... and something more ...
    }
});
```

However, when the page is ready and gets visible, the animations have been applied already. Only when I add setTimeout() and wait for a short while before adding the class, I see the element gets transformed. Is there in Ember a way to perform an action just after everything gets visible ?

Cheers